# What happens when limiting an oracle subquery

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql

A friend of mine and I recently were having a debate about this, so I was wondering if anyone here might actually know the answer.

Generally, to emulate the `LIMIT start_index,result_count` syntax of MySQL and the `LIMIT result_count OFFSET start_index` functionality of MySQL and PostgreSQL in Oracle, we use:

```
SELECT P.* FROM
  ( SELECT COL1...COLN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ID_COLUMN AS RN FROM MY_TABLE )
WHERE P.RN BETWEEN START_INDEX AND END_INDEX;
```

Instead of an explicit limit function, this alternate means needs to be used.
(If there is a better way, please let me know)

One of us argued that this means that Oracle actually fetches END_INDEX records and then only returns those records which have a rn over START_INDEX. This means that when looking for records 123,432-123,442 Oracle would retrieve 123,431 unnecessary records. It was then argued that it followed that the two open source DB's mentioned (MySQL & PgSQL) by implication have a means of shortcutting this.

The counter argument is that DBMS's are optimized to handle sub-queries, meaning that the syntax does not necessarily imply the behavior. Further, the LIMIT syntaxes are likely merely syntactic sugar which are really wrappers around what has to be stated explicitly in Oracle.

Is there any who can determine which of these is the correct interpretation? Perhaps both are correct in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that Oracle **processes** END_INDEX rows and discards rows 1 to START_INDEX-1, but it only **fetches** rows START_INDEX to END_INDEX in the cursor.

I don't know how LIMIT is implemented in the other DBMSs, but I can't imagine how they could do otherwise: how would they know they are fetching the 123,432nd row of the result set without first finding and discarding the previous 123,431 rows?

In practice, if you find yourself applying a LIMIT clause (or Oracle equivalent) with a START_INDEX of more than a few hundreds, you really need to rethink your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, the context was pagination in a custom search syntax. Sometimes we'd be looking for a user who is from NJ, but they gave us a bad email, a nickname which has no bearing on the original first name, the last name initial, and a state. This (A search on last initial and state) has returned >10k results in the pas (so 123k is a bit of an exaggeration). It seemed like our options are either use a start index in the 10k's.

Comment: note that Oracle can only avoid processing ALL the rows in the table if there is an index on `ID_COLUMN` - the lowest value for `ID_COLUMN` might be the very last record retrieved, for example. Of course, the name of the column strongly suggests there will be an index, but can't assume this :)